# How can I generate react projects with jhipster-generator?

Tags: jhipster

This question is about the usage of `jhipster-generator`.

I noticed that the react support (namely `generator-jhipster-react`) has been merged into `generator-jhipster`, but I found no guide on how to generate react projects by `generator-jhipster`.

Could anyone identify how to create react projects with `generator-jhipster`?

Answer (score 6):

As of today (2017-11-23) this has just been merged into the `master` branch, so you can use it by using [the project directly from GitHub](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).

This should be released **very** soon, as it will be included in our next version 4.11.0. As this is still in development, you will need to run it with the `--experimental` flag. This will be documented in the release notes (this is a new flag).

Comment: Please also note that it will be an early ALPHA and hence expect bugs and breaking changes. You are welcome to submit PRs to fix issues you find

Comment: @Deepu I see on the webpage that react is now on the technologies. And build passes but i'm not able to find how to generate a jhipster project with react. It is now supported or partially ? Is a professional usage possible for now ?

Comment: As mentioned above you need to use `--experimental` flag so run `jhipster --experimental` to see React in UI options. Its in early Alpha, you can use it for projects but there might be bugs and for now only default options work